# マウス位置の同期でだんだん処理が重くなる

Tags: websocket

websocketを使ってmousemoveのタイミングで位置を送信、位置が送られて来たら画像の座標に反映させる処理を書いています。

最初は重くないのですが、しばらく使っているとだんだん重くなってきます。（というか、飛び飛びになる）

原因になってそうなことはありますでしょうか。ご教授願います。

環境等

- websocket 0.2.1
- Node.js 0.10.25
- nodeサーバーで動かしています

マウス位置の送信（bodyタグに対してmousemoveのイベントの都度呼び出すようにしています）

```
var data = {
  type: 'mouse_point',
  mousePoint: {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY}
};
ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

マウスの位置情報が送信されたときにのみ反映されます

```
cursorTag.style.left = data.mousePoint.x + "px";
cursorTag.style.top = data.mousePoint.y + "px";
```

現状報告　---- 11/17 追記
　回答等ありがとうございます。この問題発生後にコードのリファクタリングを行った際に
　いつの間にか現象が発生しなくなっておりました・・・。マウス位置の送信、受信部分の記載しているコードには
　問題なかったようなので、別の問題が影響していたと考えられます。
　折角助言等頂いたにもかかわらず、このような結果になってしまい大変申し訳ございません。

Comment: 何かがリークしていると思われるので、クライアント側でメモリ使用量やGCの頻度をチェックしてみてください。断片ではなく完全なコードを示さないと原因究明は難しそうです。

Answer (score 2):

mousemoveイベントハンドラを何らかのイベント発生のたびに追加してしまい、たくさんリクエストを送ってしまっている可能性はありませんか？

マウスの位置情報を受信するたびに出力する等すれば、１イベントで複数回送信しているかどうかを確認できるものと思います。
Chromeを使っている場合はconsole.log("文字列")でコンソールに出力できます。